# Copy Paste URL is returning text instead of link using Copyenrich.js and Copyenrich-filter.js in angular 4/6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular5, angular6

I'm using copyenrich.js and copyenrich-filter.js for getting link from particular page text. It's copying the entire text as string.

I need to change the url text as anchor text.

When I copy and paste the text in notepad it is copying as text, it is ok for that.

But when i copy and paste the same text in Gmail, url related text should be changed into anchor tag.

**In Notepad.**

[image]

**In Gmail**

[image]

**I want output as like in below image.**

[image]